# Vote to close migrate to Crypto.Se?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration, cryptography

I've noticed a lot of crypto questions getting VTC'd because of being offtopic here, but there isn't an option to say 'This question belongs on crypto.stackexchange.com' and they don't really belong on stackoverflow or superuser.

Is this just because the crypto site is in beta at the moment? It'd be good to have I think.

Comment: Just to note the obvious, the cryptography site has now been out of beta for quite some time and going strong. Feel free to migrate, as there seem quite few questions with the [tag:cryptography] tag that remain here without being about practical application.

Answer (score 6):

Yes - beta sites do not show up in the list of migration options, so for those, just flag for a mod and list which site you think they should be sent to.

Once it is out of beta, it can be added to our migration list - judging by our stats it probably will...I think we get up to 4 destinations.